# Products are in the database, but not showing in Fragment in my android app

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to learn android and I have this shopping list, using the Cloud Firestore database. When I want to add products in the database, it works (I can see them in Firebase), but when I want to display them, they don't show up..any ideas why? Thank you!

This is a part of the `onCreateView()` function in `ShoppingListFragment`:

```
    rootRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    shoppingListProductsRef = rootRef.collection("products").document(shoppingListId).collection("shoppingListProducts");

    RecyclerView recyclerView = shoppingListViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    TextView emptyView = shoppingListViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.empty_view);
    ProgressBar progressBar = shoppingListViewFragment.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

    Query query = shoppingListProductsRef.whereEqualTo("izInShoppingList", izInShoppingList)
            .orderBy("productName", Query.Direction.ASCENDING);

    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<ProductModel> firestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<ProductModel>()
            .setQuery(query, ProductModel.class)
            .build();

    firestoreRecyclerAdapter =
            new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<ProductModel, ProductViewHolder>(firestoreRecyclerOptions) {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProductViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull ProductModel model) {
                    holder.setProduct(getContext(), shoppingListViewFragment, userEmail, userName, shoppingListModel, model);
                }

                @Override
                public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_product, parent, false);
                    return new ProductViewHolder(view);
                }

                @Override
                public void onDataChanged() {
                    if (progressBar != null) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    if (getItemCount() == 0) {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        emptyView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public int getItemCount() {
                    return super.getItemCount();
                }
            };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(firestoreRecyclerAdapter);

    return shoppingListViewFragment;
}
```

Comment: There could be multiple causes start by setting: `recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);`

Comment: What is the value of `shoppingListId` in your reference? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: Thank you @Yupi , I added that and it worked :)

Comment: @AlexMamo I added recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false); and it workes now, but I`m having another problem when trying to move a product from "Shopping list" to "Product list". I will add a different question

Comment: @Andra Good to hear that ;) Yes, should ask a different question.